# For loop out of range

Tags: c#

I got this problem I need to solve and for some reason I just can't see why this isn't working today.

So my problem is I am trying to do this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < _positions.Count; i+=3) {
   Vector3 v0 = _positions[i + 0];
   Vector3 v1 = _positions[i + 1];
   Vector3 v2 = _positions[i + 2];
   [...]  
}
```

and this is not working. `_postions` is an List of Vector3 where vector3 is a struct with 3 floats. The thing is that I can get this to work

```
for (var i = 0; i < _indices.Count; i += 3) {
   int i0 = _indices[i].Value;
   int i1 = _indices[i + 1].Value;
   int i2 = _indices[i + 2].Value;
}
```

and _indices is a

```
List<int?>
```

Comment: In the first example, you're looking at _position.Count in your loop, but you use _positions inside the body. So long as the count is divisible by 3, then you should be fine, but you should cater for that.

Comment: Use `_positions.Count` not `_position.Count` (note the plural).

Comment: so what you are saying is that its mostly luck that _indices work?

Comment: jeeped yeah thats a typo in the example the real code is a bit diffrent

Comment: If your array length is divisible by 3, then you'll be fine, but if not, then it will bomb as soon as you try to access elements from the final remainder of 1 or 2. Wrap it with `if (_positions.Count % 3 == 0) { stuff } else { flag issue };`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your looping code is fine, but it assumes that the array in question is divisible by 3. If there's a remainder of 1 or 2 left over, then you're going to try to access elements beyond the limit of the array.

E.g. if you have an array of 10 elements, then it will go through the loop three times and there's still more to process at the end, the 10th element, however the 11th & 12th elements do not exist, so it will bomb when you try to access those elements, as your code assumes their existence.

Test that the array is divisible by 3 prior to execution, to be certain, or simply ensure that it always will be in your code.

```
if (_positions.Count % 3 == 0)
{
    // Processing here e.g. ...
    for (int i = 0; i < _positions.Count; i+=3) {
        Vector3 v0 = _positions[i + 0];
        Vector3 v1 = _positions[i + 1];
        Vector3 v2 = _positions[i + 2];
        [...]
    }
}
else
{
    // Flag issue here, either on console or throw an exception...
    Console.WriteLine("Positions array length must be divisible by 3");
}
```

If you wish to ignore any remaining values (1 or 2 of them), then you can subtract the modulus of 3 from the count in your for loop to ensure that the for loop iterates over groups of 3 only without the shorter remainder, ignoring the discrepancy silently

For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < _positions.Count - (_positions.Count % 3); i+=3) {
    Vector3 v0 = _positions[i + 0];
    Vector3 v1 = _positions[i + 1];
    Vector3 v2 = _positions[i + 2];
    [...]
}
```